# On what basis were the characters selected?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Now that Thanos has all the 6 Infinity stones at the end of *Avengers: Infinity War*, he is the most powerful creature in the universe. When he snapped his fingers during the last scene of the movie Drax, Starlord, Black Panther and many more started disintegrating into dust.

And in the post-credits scene, Nick Fury also died.

On what basis were they "chosen" for destruction?

Comment: They are NOT dead, just floating around in miniscule pieces after getting pulverised ;)

Comment: [This answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/88481/34478) basically addresses your question.

Comment: Perhaps you're asking about the mechanics of the gauntlet w.r.t. the stones, and everyone disintegrating? Like, which stones are used, and in what way? If so, @Obie2.0 provides a relevant link.

Comment: They were chosen for removal based on assumed audience appreciation. They will be restored based on who has new films coming out. :)

Comment: as @Paulie_D said, on what basis they were chosen?

Comment: @Charles No. I am asking why only certain people were chosen by thanos? or maybe they are not chosen by thanos? it could be a random eradication.

Comment: @AmanVerma It was completely random. Thanos mentions this at one point in the film.

Answer (score 8):

Thanos explained during a conversation with Doctor Strange

> When Thanos was explaining his past to Doctor Strange on Titan, he said that the **re-balancing of the universe should occur by random selection of people to be eliminated**.

As the article asks, this raises later issues & other questions such as..

> However, if this selection was random, why did the original Avengers just happen to survive?
>
> Also, the disintegration seemed to affect Spider-Man differently than everyone else. While everyone else simply faded from existence instantaneously, Spider-Man seems to have felt the effects. He knew that he was disappearing and it took him a lot longer to fade away than the rest of the world.
>
> Was this simply a way to show an emotional moment between him and Stark, or was there another reason as to why Spider-Man was affected differently?
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://screenrant.com/avengers-infinity-war-makes-no-sense-plot-holes/)</sup>

Comment: Because [spidey-sense](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/187170/13024)